# Clear tableofcontents page in memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, memoir

How do I clear the `\tableofcontents` page in `memoir`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{titlingpage}
  \maketitle
\end{titlingpage}

% i need clear this page
{\thispagestyle{empty} %but is not work
\tableofcontents}

\chapter{Memoir com Estilo de Página}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This source (http://nw360.blogspot.com/2007/10/creat-empty-page-in-latex.html) recommends writing `\mbox{}` after `\thispagestyle{empty}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) provides ToC hooks (`\cfttocbeforelisthook` and `\cfttocafterlisthook`) that could be modified to adjust the page style headings:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\title{My title}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlingpage}
  \maketitle
\end{titlingpage}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cfttocbeforelisthook}{\pagestyle{empty}\let\ps@plain\ps@empty}
\renewcommand{\cfttocafterlisthook}{\cleardoublepage\pagestyle{headings}}
\makeatother

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Memoir com Estilo de Página}

\end{document}
```

The above sets the page style to `empty` and also copies the `empty` page style into the `plain` page style, since this is used as the first page for `\tableofcontents` (like all chapters). At the end of the ToC, `\cleardoublepage` flushes all pages and resets the page style to `headings`.

Comment: Thanks Werner, and its work in others class, example, book, report?

Comment: @RegisdaSilva: Are you asking or saying?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a bit different solution for the same problem.

In memoir doc 9.2.2 (148. p.)

> Essentially, the ToC, LoF and LoT titles use the same format as the
>   chapter titles, and will be typeset according to the current
>   chapterstyle. You can modify their appearance by either using a
>   different chapterstyle for them than for the actual chapters, or by
>   changing some of the macros. As examples:
>
> Doing 
>   `\renewcommand{\printXtitle}[1]{\hfill\Large\itshape #1}`
>
> print the title right justified in a Large italic font.
>   For a bold centered title you can do
>   `\renewcommand{\printXtitle}[1]{\centering\Large\bfseries #1}`
>
> Writing `\renewcommand{\afterXtitle}{% >\thispagestyle{empty}\afterchaptertitle}`
>
> will result in the first page of the listing using the empty pagestyle
>   instead of the default chapter pagestyle.

So putting

```
\renewcommand{\aftertoctitle}{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}\afterchaptertitle}
```

does the same job for me.