# Clear tableofcontents page in book or report

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, report

How do I clear the `\tableofcontents` page in book or report?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

% i need clear this page
{\thispagestyle{empty} %but is not work
\tableofcontents}

\chapter{Book tableofcontents without page number}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following in your document preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\@starttoc{toc}}{\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}\@starttoc{toc}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

% i need clear this page
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagestyle{headings}% ...or whichever heading style you use
\cleardoublepage
%...
\end{document}
```

You patch `\tableofcontents` using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to set the current page style to `empty`, as well as the following page styles (if your ToC spans more than one page) to `empty`. `\clearpage` flushes the current page (last one of the ToC), after which you can reset your page style to `headings` (or whatever you like). The additional `\cleardoublepage` makes sure that there's an additional page flush (if necessary) to make sure the chapter starts on a recto page.

The approach is similar to that followed in [Clear tableofcontents page in memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38651/clear-tableofcontents-page-in-memoir).

Comment: all odd page are without number too.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva: Look back at your original question. There is no mention that you want odd pages to have numbers and even pages to have no number. Is this what you want? That is, do you want odd pages to have numbers, but even pages have no number? Where should these numbers be? In the header, or the footer? And should this configuration hold for *just* the ToC? It helps being specific about these things, since a solution will be much more forthcoming that way.

Comment: I want numbering on all pages except the tableofcontents, but this is not happening with your code.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva: If I compile my code with a `\chapter{Book tableofcontents without page number} \lipsum` after `\pagestyle{headings}`, I get a 4-page document. Page 1 and 2 have no headings (and no page numbers), while page 3 and 4 have the regular `plain` (for chapter first pages) and `headings` headings. Do you want page 2 to have headings as well?

Comment: yes!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @RegisdaSilva: If your `\tableofcontents` contains only a single page, then @ AlanMunn's answer should do exactly what you want. If not, I'll work on something that could do what you're after.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva: See my updated answer. By the way, I like @ StephanKottwitz' approach of adding the page style specification via `\addtocontents` much better than my `etoolbox` approach. As such you don't actually need `etoolbox`.

Answer (score 5):

I would combine `\pagestyle` and add `\thispagestyle` to the `.toc`file, to have effect on the first page of the ToC.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}} % at the beginning of your document
     % writes \thispagestyle{empty} into the .toc file`, so here at the beginning
\pagestyle{empty}% switches to empty page style
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage% clear the page before changing back the page style
\pagestyle{headings}% switching back to the page style you use in your document
\chapter{Book table of contents without page number}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

`\protect` is used to prevent expansion of `\thispagestyle` before it's written to the `.toc` file.

Comment: This is *much* cleaner and `etoolbox`-free!